# How to use a 0505 DC-DC isolator?

Tags: dc, dc-dc-converter, lithium-ion, isolation

I'm trying to build a device powered by a 3s Li-po battery and charged with 3 TP4056 modules, one for each cell. I did some googling around and found out that it wouldn't work due to the common ground of the TP4056.

I found a few alternatives and one of it is by using a 0505 DC-DC isolator. Can someone teach me how to use the isolator? And what are the disadvantages of using one? I've tried googling, but didn't find an answer.

[image]

Comment: Which isolator are you intending to use, and what is your power source?

Comment: @Bruce Abbott 0505 dc-dc isolator. Either a 5v usb power or a buck converter stepped down to 5v from 12v

Comment: _Which_ 0505 dc-dc isolator?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest against the 0505 because they are only 1 W isolators. This means that the current at 5 V would have to be less than 200 mA. I would suggest going for Hi-Link 220 V to 5 V converters such as [this one](https://www.ebay.com/itm/5PCS-HLK-PM01-AC-DC-220V-to-5V-Step-Down-Power-Supply-Module-Household-Switch-/221950422327?hash=item33ad46ad37:g:8WYAAOSwxN5WVRA-) from eBay.

This module is 3 W so the charging current would be three times higher at 600 mA. You can use three of these modules in parallel.

Make sure you configure the TP4056 resistors to limit the current.

If you must use the 0505 due to its small size or other constraints (like only having a +5 V source), it's very simple to use. Supply +5 V and GND at the input and you'll get isolated +5 V and GND at the output (see [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/468/ROE-766139.pdf) for pinouts). You will have to cut the 6 wires going to + and - of the TP4056 and inject the 0505 between them (use the cut up end of the wires close to the power supply as input and the other end as output of the 0505).

Just remember to limit the TP4056 charging current to 100 mA or so to ensure a long life of the 0505, otherwise they might have a reduced life span.